# Center Image but keep it to the left CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, centering

I am trying to put an image to the center of the webpage but still keeping it to the left, using css. This means that the right side of the image is "touching" the center of the page. Not exactly touching though, since I want about 50px of space between the image and the center. This is because I want to put a text to the right of it.
I have been trying to do this with the following code in CSS:

```
.Image1 img {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-right: 350px;
}
```

This makes the image exactly where I want it. I would then want to put a chunk of text next to that image, about 100 px to the right of it with a width of 300px. I am not sure how to do this, could anyone help me?

Comment: A diagram would help hugely if you can mock one up. The instructions might allow too much scope for wrongful interpretation

Comment: you can use `transform:translatex(-50px)` for image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you actually do not want to center the image, but the combined block of image and text.

Create a container to hold these two and center that..

```
<div class="group">
  <img src="..." /> 
  <div class="text">the text here</div>
</div>
```

and use

```
.group{
    width:700px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.group > img{float:left;width:300px;}
.group .text{float:right;width:300px;}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/2yL3u57x/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.center{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
p{
width:40px;
margin-left: 9px;
float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg" />
<p>Lorem ipsum text</p>
</div>
```